# How To remove ugly font smoothing on ipad apps

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app with xcode 4.0.2 and im having trouble getting my fonts to look sharp and clear when i set the font size below 15px. It appears that there is some level of font smoothing being applied to the font and it doesn't look good at all. I've tried several different fonts and i get the same effect. Is there a way i can turn this off?

Comment: It might be text shadow.

Comment: not at all, i've tried removing shadows and it makes no difference, there is clearly a level of font smoothing being applied. Im thinking of looking for a font that is optimised for small sizes...

Comment: Is this in a UILabel/UITextField/UITextView, or are you drawing it yourself with Coretext?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually drawing on non fractioned coordinates. If for example you start drawing on X = 0.5 and Y = 0.0, your text will look lousy. Same goes for vertical coordinates. In case your coordinates are resulting from a calculation, simply add a cast towards an integer like this:

```
CGPoint startDrawingAt = CGPointMake((int)x, (int)y);
```

Or use proper rounding:

```
CGPoint startDrawingAt = CGPointMake(roundf(x), roundf(y));
```